# Using Django's ImageField, how to store files in STATIC_ROOT?

Tags: django

Using Django's `ImageField()`, how would I store the image file in `STATIC_ROOT` rather than `MEDIA_ROOT`?

I realise this is a bad idea for images which are uploaded through the admin, but these images are stored with the rest of the code in git, and attached to the objects when the site is set up using a script which imports all the objects' data. The images are not added/edited/deleted after this.

Comment: What if you change the `MEDIA_ROOT` path to that of `STATIC_ROOT`?

Comment: Django [insists that they be different](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-MEDIA_ROOT).

Answer (score 4):

You can import `FileSystemStorage` and specify your custom upload path and pass the `FileSystemStorage` object as an argument in the `ImageField()`

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from django.conf.settings import STATIC_ROOT


upload_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=STATIC_ROOT, base_url='/uploads')


class ABCModel(models.Model):
    ...
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='/your_image_name', storage=upload_storage)
```

References:

- [FileField - ImageField inherits from FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#filefield)
- [FileSystemStorage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/files/storage/#the-filesystemstorage-class)

Comment: Thanks. The trouble with this is that it stores the files in the `static collected` location, which isn't in git.

Comment: But you want the images to be stored in the static location?

Comment: Yes, but in `appname/static/` rather than `projectname/staticfiles/` (which is my `STATIC_ROOT`).

Comment: What if you do `FileSystemStorage(location=appname/static/, base_url='/uploads')`?